# What is JOB_flow_overrides in Airflow EmrCreateJobFlowOperator? When to use it

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x, mwaa

I have seen people creating JOB_flow_overrides in creating EMR. I have set up all those master and slave nodes required in emr_default (extra), DO I still need it? In what cases will use this parameter?

Comment: What about emr_default, even in that we define master and slaves nodes

Answer (score 1):

`job_flow_overrides` is used to create a new emr cluster every time the dag is ran.
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/operators/emr.html

Comment: How does it compare to emr_default? In both cases we define master and slave nodes